# mod_symlink or something to deliver files from outside the doc root?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, symbolic-link

I'm wondering if there is an apache mod that can handle delivering files outside of the document root?

My specific example is that I would like to, in my vhost config if possible, rewrite ROBOTS.txt so that I can provide a generic "disallow all" for use with hosts used for testing deployment.

The only alternative I can see is that I have a ROBOTS.txt replacement occuring in my deployment vhost setup script. I know I could probably use mod_rewrite, however the browser would still be aware that I'm pointing it to a different ROBOTS.txt location wouldn't it? As the ROBOTS is a disallow all, I don't want to have the browser aware of the rewrite, and risk it indexing the sites.

Thanks for any advice :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite will do a rewrite (not a redirect) if possible. But you want [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).